# Json array deserialize

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonserializer

How to deserialize below json array. unable to fetch the field_options values and array of field_options. i am using DataContractJsonSerializer to deserialize.
I need to fetch the field_options like size then  if field_type is dropdown i will required the values of  field_options -> options -> lebel and checked value as well as include_blank_option.

```
string jsonString = @"[{""fields"":[{""label"":""Untitled"",""field_type"":""paragraph"",""required"":true,""field_options"":{""size"":""small""},""cid"":""c2""},{""label"":""Untitled"",""field_type"":""text"",""required"":true,""field_options"":{""size"":""small""},""cid"":""c6""},{""label"":""Untitled"",""field_type"":""dropdown"",""required"":true,""field_options"":{""options"":[{""label"":""kjhkjh"",""checked"":false},{""label"":"",hkjkhkj"",""checked"":false}],""include_blank_option"":true},""cid"":""c8""}]}]}";

    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<field>));
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
    var obj = (List<field>)ser.ReadObject(stream);


        foreach (Person sp in obj[0].fields)
        {
            Response.Write(sp.cid + sp.field_type + sp.label + sp.required + "<BR>");
            List<sizee> si = sp.field_options;
            foreach (sizee sz in si)
            {
                Response.Write(sz.size);
            }
        }

[DataContract]
class field
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Person> fields { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string label { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string field_type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string required { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string cid { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<sizee> field_options { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class sizee
{
    [DataMember]
    public string size { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<option> size { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class option
{
    [DataMember]
    public string checke { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string label { get; set; }
}
```

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I usually find writing sample data to a file helps solves these type issues. I made the classes public and fixed a duplicate property size in one of the classes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            field f = new field()
            {
                fields = new List<Person>() {
                    new Person() {
                        cid = "abc",
                        field_type = "def",
                        label = "ghi",
                        required = "true",
                        field_options = new List<sizee>() {
                            new sizee() {
                                size = "AAA",
                                options = new List<option>() {
                                    new option() {
                                        checke = "123",
                                        label = "456",
                                    },
                                   new option() {
                                        checke = "789",
                                        label = "012",
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                           new sizee() {
                                size = "BBB",
                                options = new List<option>() {
                                    new option() {
                                        checke = "321",
                                        label = "654",
                                    },
                                   new option() {
                                        checke = "987",
                                        label = "210",
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                   new Person() {
                        cid = "xyz",
                        field_type = "def",
                        label = "ghi",
                        required = "true",
                        field_options = new List<sizee>() {
                            new sizee() {
                                size = "AAA",
                                options = new List<option>() {
                                    new option() {
                                        checke = "123",
                                        label = "456",
                                    },
                                   new option() {
                                        checke = "789",
                                        label = "012",
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                           new sizee() {
                                size = "BBB",
                                options = new List<option>() {
                                    new option() {
                                        checke = "321",
                                        label = "654",
                                    },
                                   new option() {
                                        checke = "987",
                                        label = "210",
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(field));
            FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(FILENAME);
            ser.WriteObject(stream, f);

            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();

        }
    }



    [DataContract]
    public class field
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<Person> fields { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string label { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string field_type { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string required { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string cid { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<sizee> field_options { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class sizee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string size { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<option> options { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class option
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string checke { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string label { get; set; }
    }
}

​
```